How does Qt gauge whether a file exists or not, given spaces in the file path?
qDebug()<< QFileInfo::exists("C:\\Users\\chenz\\Desktop\\Docker Desktop.lnk");
qDebug()<< QFileInfo::exists("C:/Users/chenz/Desktop/Clash Verge.lnk");
QFileInfo p{"C:/Users/chenz/Desktop/Docker Desktop.lnk"};
qDebug()<< p.exists();

qDebug()<< QFileInfo::exists("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Update\\GoogleUpdate.exe");
qDebug()<< QFileInfo::exists("C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Update/GoogleUpdate.exe");

the files do exist in the place.
but first three of them print false, the left print true
I've find it's due to the spaces in the path string. If the spaces appear in the file basename, it prints false; otherwise, it has no effect.
so how to deal with the path with spaces?
test on : windows 10, Qt 5.15.2 MSVC2019 32bit

A guess here, but maybe try replacing spaces with \  instead?

"The files do exist": the first three are links, do their related paths (the files they point to) exist? Note that the targets must be actual files.

@musicamante exist. clicking on the shortcut, the related program will launch

@Arthur That's not really relevant: windows shortcuts can also "link" to control panel sections (IIRC, using their system UIDs within brackets). Check the actual path of those targets by opening the property panels of those links. In fact, a more accurate test would be to reproduce what you mention: just create a real file with spaces in its name and test QFileInfo::exists() with that.

@musicamante it works. I get the true real path, QFileInfo::exists() return true, even if spaces in the basename

@Arthur So, assuming that C:/path/with/spaces in name.lnk points to an existing file named C:/path/with/spaces in name.txt, are you saying that the former doesn't work, and the latter does? If that's the case, let's do further checking: 1. is the path used by the link an absolute/explicit one, or does it use relative paths (eg. ../../) or placeholders (eg. %ProgramFiles%)? 2. is the link in a shared/network resource? 3. does the program have permissions to access either the link or the file? 4. does anything change if you use the full constructor instead (QFileInfo(path)::exists())?

@Arthur Also note that the .lnk management of QFileInfo is somehow broken by Qt's own admission: it's inconsistent and often unreliable, since it treats windows links similarly to *nix symlinks, which is inappropriate as it is wrong, because such "links" are, in reality, actual files with their own contents and size.

@musicamante QFileInfo::exists("C:\\Users\\chenz\\Desktop\\Docker Desktop.lnk") the lnk itself exists, but it return false. and then I get the realpath of link target, check with QFileInfo::exists it returns true.  however,  QFileInfo::symLinkTarget return value of the link is different from the real target path. I opened a new issue here issue.

@musicamante then, I've another test. I make a new file on the desktop, whose name is filled with spaces --p 123.txt and then I make a shortcut for it -- p 123.lnk.  QFileInfo::exists("/path/to/p 123.lnk") returns true, and the QFileInfo::symLinkTarget will return right path. in contrast with the previous example , the QFileInfo::exists returns false and QFileInfo::symLinkTarget returns wrong path. so the root cause may be QFileInfo::symLinkTarget

@Arthur It seems another annoying Windows inconsistency caused by internal management of special paths (program files, users, etc.). Did you try the full QFileInfo constructor? Note that, while often similar in behavior, it's not the same as the static function.
